# Understanding behavior of cout.operator<<()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream, cout

According to the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070606/cout-and-cin-are-not-functions-so-what-are-they), `cout << expr` is equivalent to `cout.operator<<(expr)`.

According to responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763067/difference-between-cout-x-and-cout-operator-x), the statement above is untrue.

According to my own testing, `cout.operator<<()` is the same as `cout <<` when given an integer.  When given a float, `cout.operator<<()` coerces it to an integer.  When given a string literal, as in `cout.operator<<("hello world")`, it outputs what appears to be a memory address.  And when given a variable holding a std::string, it gives a compiler error.

Could anyone give a beginner-to-intermediate-level explanation of what's going on?

Comment: "*`cout << expr` is equivalent of `cout.operator<<(expr)`*" is not universally true. The answer from the 2nd question + 1st comment explain that. Not sure if that counts as duplicate... Perhaps this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809463/is-there-any-advantage-to-implementing-functions-as-free-functions-rather-than-m/36809565#36809565

Answer (score 5):

**It depends on `expr`.**

The answers to both questions are speaking to that specific case, not a blanket guarantee.

In fact, some of the `operator<<`s are [free](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) [functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), and some are [member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

Consult your favourite C++ reference to find out which.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalency of `cout << expr` and `cout.operator<<(expr)` depends on what `expr` is.

If it lands up being a "built in" type, that `cout` "knows" about, then yes, it is equivalent to `cout.operator<<(expr)` (a member function).

If it is a "user type" (and `std::string` counts here), then it is an overloaded non-member method with a signature akin to `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::string&);` etc.

> Why does `cout.operator<<("hello world")` print a memory address?

The best member method overload to the above (since it is being forced to use the member method, is `ostream& operator<<(const void* value);` which outputs the value of the pointer (not what is being pointed to).

By contrast, `cout << "hello world"` calls the non-member overload `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const char*)` and this in-turn inserts each character into the output.